# Cannot edit task list item after completed/no "save as draft" for task forms

Tags: workflow, infopath, tasks

I have built a SPD workflow in SP2010 (collect data from user) that collects a single text field from the user (this is just a test case, my real task form has many more fields).

When the user completes this task, they are unable to re-edit the task item fields. They can view the fields, but not update the fields. Is this functionality not possible?

In the greater scheme of things, I am trying to create a save as draft functionality in these task forms (because it was removed in 2007). This does not look like it is possible, either through the workflow itself or through customizing the submit action in InfoPath.

I have tried a number of things, including checking list item permissions, but am coming up empty handed. Is there any way to edit these task list items after they have been completed once?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the desired option would be to create a plain old task (can be your own customized task content type) for the user instead.  This will allow the user to fill it out, save it, and return to it later to mark complete at which point the workflow will carry on.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "plain old task"? I am using the collect data from a user workflow action because it sends an email to the user notifying them to fill out the information in the task item.

Comment: I mean creating an item in a task list, if the task list is configured to notify users, they'll still get an email about it and a link to fill out the item.